# Thymeleaf content assist not working with Spring Tools

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-tool-suite

I installed Thymeleaf plugin 3.0.0 for sts 4.9.0

I used : xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"

error log :

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataSource cannot be found by org.thymeleaf.extras.eclipse.core_3.0.0.202005310144
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:516)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:171)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
... 188 more

Answer (score 0):

Probably worth checking the Thymeleaf Eclipse plugin repo for related issues. This one looks related: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-eclipse-plugin/issues/100

Comment: But i could not understand how to fix this